# Caching GET response in Javascript Vanilla

Tags: javascript

I've noticed that Firefox does not cache GET requests automatically. Following the code I use:

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("GET","page.php?val=" + val,true);
ajax.send();
```

With jquery is possible to give `cache: true;`, how can I save in the cache with Vanilla Javascript (client side)? Is also possible to decide for how long? Can you give me an example of code? Thank you in advance!

Comment: `cache: true`, does not *guarantee* the file will be cached. You need to emit the correct cache-related headers from your server (`Cache-Control`, `Last-Modified`, etc), *then* both FireFox and jQuery stand a chance of caching the file. See http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/

Comment: Internet Explorer automatically saves GET responses. For the first time I can say Internet Explorer wins: D

Answer (score 1):

Web caching is largely controlled by the headers sent from the Server (Expires:, etc.). Browsers sometimes "cheat" and don't really cache even though the headers would allow them to  ...probably because the user had used their UI to turn off caching, for example by setting the cache size to zero. But browsers that "cheat" the other direction, caching anyway even though the headers don't allow it, are (for good reason) extremely uncommon.

If caching is not happening for you, it's a function of the file and the server (or perhaps the browser configuration), not of any browser type or version. (To say the same thing a different way, your Firefox would cache just fine if the Server sent the needed headers.) The headers are controlled a variety of ways by different servers and different providers. For the Apache server, the nitty-gritty may be in a ".htaccess" file, pre-written templates of which are often available.

To a first approximation, with HTML4, you simply cannot control web caching from the client side, no matter what tool you use and no matter what your program does. A generic exception is provided by the new "online application cache" or "appcache" in HTML5  ...but with other restrictions, for example those about "one per site" and "same origin".

Answer (score 1):

You can cache responses using a simple hash, something like:

```
var cache = {};
function getData(variable) {
    if (cache[variable]) {
        return cache[variable];
    }

    // previous ajax code to get the data...
    // in the response handler, do:
    cache[variable] = data;
}
```

That's a naive implementation of a caching mechanism: only works for the lifetime of the page (i.e., until the page is refreshed or navigated away from), doesn't have any expiration mechanism, and other shortcomings I'm sure. For instance, you could use `localStorage` to get around the refresh issue.

But hey, I'm not getting paid to write this :).